# Incoming SMS to trigger code in an MVC application

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

Im in the process of developing a CRM where, a client can send an SMS and trigger some event driven code to update a database.  Ive been looking at Twilio pretty hard, and looked at all their documentation and none of their API documentation covers this particular context.

Can anyone help?

Comment: Really? https://www.twilio.com/docs/quickstart/csharp/sms/hello-monkey

Comment: Genuinely didnt see that document. Ta

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you setup a Twilio SMS number, you configure an HTTP location for Twilio to POST or GET in response to an SMS message. You would build a service such as Web API to handle the XML that Twilio would post/get against your endpoint and do whatever your want on your database.

Here's a reference to the Twilio .NET/C# quick start for SMS. Your endpoint will get called when the SMS is received. You can return a basic XML document () or add xml elements that tell Twilio what to do, such as reply with another SMS. Twilio calls this "TwiML". Regardless, you'll get enough details to update your DB and do whatever else you might want to do.

Link to Quick Start: https://www.twilio.com/docs/quickstart/csharp/sms/hello-monkey

Comment: Genuinely didnt see that document. Ta